# Python - Find the shortest word in a list

Tags: python, string, list, cpu-word, shortest

Hi all I know there may have been a few similar questions asked already but I would appreciate it if you could give me a more specific solution for what I have attempted.

Basically the program should return the shortest word in the list. The shortest word cannot be an empty string. <-- I'm also not sure how to do this part.

Thanks for the help! : )

Main Program:

```
    n = int((input("Enter amount of words: "))
    sw = st.word(n)
    print("The shortest word is: {0:.s}" .format(sw))
```

Function:

```
    def word(n):

        l1 = []

        for i in range(n):
            words = str(input("Enter word: "))
            l1.append(words)

        s = l1
        nxt = l1

        for i in range(n+1): 
            if s[i] < nxt[i+1]:
                smallest = s[i]
            if nxt[i+1] < s[i]:
                smallest = nxt[i+1]
        return smallest
```

Answer (score 7):

You could just use build in [min](http://%20l%20=%20[%22ab%22,%20%22abc%22,%20%22%22,%20%22fff%22,%20%22gdfgfdg%22,%22a%22,%20%223455%22]%20%20%20print(min((word%20for%20word%20in%20l%20if%20word),%20key=len))) function:

```
l = ["ab", "abc", "", "fff", "gdfgfdg","a", "3455"]


print(min((word for word in l if word), key=len))
# results in: a
```

Some explanation:

- `(word for word in l if word)` is [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions),
- `if word` condition assures that empty strings are not used,
- `key=len`
  uses length of each word to look for a minium

Comment: Another solution using `filter`: `min(filter(None, l), key=len)`

Comment: @soon Thx. You could make an answer, showing alternative solution.

Answer (score 5):

You should always prefer to use built-in functions rather than writing your own (maybe except the cases when you are learning). `@Marcin` describes the work of `min` function very well, so, I want to present you a `filter` function as a replacement for generator expressions.

Let's see the way how `min` and `filter` may work together:

```
In [1]: l = ["ab", "abc", "", "fff", "gdfgfdg","a", "3455"]

In [2]: min(filter(None, l), key=len)
Out[2]: 'a'
```

It may be less intuitive, comparing with `@Marcin` solution, but I prefer to use high order functions, instead of generators. Reading the text, where one word has 40% frequency (`word for word in l if word` - 3 / 7) - no, thanks :).

Just a quote from documentation:

```
In [3]: filter?
Type:        type
String form: <class 'filter'>
Namespace:   Python builtin
Docstring:
filter(function or None, iterable) --> filter object

Return an iterator yielding those items of iterable for which function(item)
is true. If function is None, return the items that are true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want first minimum word.

```
n = raw_input('Enter words breaking with spaces:')

wordList = n.split()

print min([(word, len(word)) for word in wordList], key=lambda x:x[1])
```

If you want all the minimum words.

```
n = raw_input('Enter words breaking with spaces:')

wordList = n.split()

minimunWordLength = min([len(word) for word in wordList])
minimunWords = filter(lambda x:len(x) == minimunWordLength,wordList)

print minimunWords
```

Answer (score 0):

**Algo:**

1. Get User Input for numbers words by `raw_input()`. Handle exception handling when user enters wrong input i.e. non integer value.
2. Check enter number is grater then 0 or not. If yes the go to next steps. otherwise print `You enter value less then 1.`
3. Call `getSmallWord` function, pass words counter as argument.
4. Use `for` loop and `range` function to accept word from the user and add to `set` variable because words may be duplicates from the user, set will not add duplicate words.
5. Assign first element from the `set` as smallest and remove this word from the `set`.
6. Iterate every element from the `set` and check if current element i.e. word length is smaller then smallest word then assign this word as smallest.
7. Return smallest word.
8. print result.

**Demo:**

```
def getSmallWord(n):
    #- Use set because set will add one one word when user enter duplicate words.
    words = set()
    for i in range(n):
        word = raw_input("Enter word: ")
        words.add(word)

    #- Assign First word as smallest.
    smallest_word = words.pop()

    #- Iterate words from the 1 index. because we assign 0th element as Smallest.
    for word in words:
        #- Check Lenght of current elemnt from the User Input with the Smallest Word.
        if len(word)<len(smallest_word):
            smallest_word = word

    return smallest_word


if __name__=="__main__":
    try:
        n = int(raw_input("Enter amount of words: "))
    except ValueError:
        n = 5
        print "Enter Wrong number input. Number of Words are %d"%n      

    if n>0:
        sw = getSmallWord(n)
        print "The shortest word is: %s" %sw
    else:
        print "You enter value less then 1."
```

**Output:**

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow/anna$ python 8.py 
Enter amount of words: 5
Enter word: qwert
Enter word: asdf
Enter word: as
Enter word: asdf
Enter word: qwer
The shortest word is: as
```

---

**Note:**

Use raw_input() for Python 2.x

Use input() for Python 3.x